# angular material image scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, angular-material

I have more than one image in a row. And I need to handle that with horizontal scrollbar. Is that possible in angular material. I have tried the code as below. But images were placed one above the other.

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-align="start center"  md-scroll-x>
                <a href="" ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <img ng-src="{{item.src}}" class="md-card-image radius">
                </a>
            </md-content>
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and it works as expected i don't see any issues in your snippet.

```
 <md-content layout="row" layout-align="start center" md-scroll-x>
    <a href="" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img ng-src="{{item}}" class="md-card-image radius">
    </a>

  </md-content>
```

working code [here](http://codepen.io/cyrilcherian/pen/XXbwpY?editors=101)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have tried taking the build by using some images? In the build you can see the images are rolling over.

Comment: you mean in my example teh images are rolling over?

Comment: yes, while taking the build. the issue exist in apk only. In browser its working fine